# What does Console.WriteLine() call behind the scenes?

Tags: c#

I'm interested in how calling Console.WriteLine() actually displays text.

I've had a look at the source code from:
http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/textwriter.cs,5f99350fdf8dae53
and can see that this method from TextWriter ends up getting called:

```
        // Writes a character to the text stream. This default method is empty,
        // but descendant classes can override the method to provide the
        // appropriate functionality.
        //
        public virtual void Write(char value) {
        }
```

What is the descendant class that overrides this method? And what is the implementation?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Check out the source from the [CoreCLR](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/775003a4c72f0acc37eab84628fcef541533ba4e/src/mscorlib/src/System/LowLevelConsole.cs) branch, which Microsoft are hosting on github:

```
    [SecuritySafeCritical]
    static Console()
    {
        _outputHandle = new SafeFileHandle(Win32Native.GetStdHandle(Win32Native.STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), false);
    }

    [SecuritySafeCritical]
    public static unsafe void Write(string s)
    {
        byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(s);
        fixed (byte * pBytes = bytes)
        {
            int bytesWritten;
            Win32Native.WriteFile(_outputHandle, pBytes, bytes.Length, out bytesWritten, IntPtr.Zero);
        }
    }
```

There are two things going on here: in the static ctor, the code is getting a Win32 handle to the STD_OUTPUT virtual file, which wraps the standard output to the process's attached console. And in the Write method, it's writing the data to that file.

Basically, it wraps the internal OS facilities for writing to a console, which is virtual file.

Comment: How did you find that? And why can't you navigate there if you start off at one of the Console.WriteLine() overloaded methods?

Comment: @Backwards_Dave: Unless you use a tool like DotPeek or connect to Microsoft's symbol servers, or find a way to set the github source as your symbol server, there's no source for your IDE to look at, so it doesn't. If you set that up, it can.

Answer (score 4):

Based on the reference source:

- [`Console.WriteLine(string)` calls `Console.Out.WriteLine(string)`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/console.cs,5ac7c4fda643413b)
- [`Console.Out` is initialized by calling `InitializeStdOutError(true)`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/console.cs,7957ab492848cd86)
- `InitializeStdOutError` returns [a `TextWriter.Synchronized` wrapper](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/console.cs,375) around [a `StreamWriter` wrapper (with `AutoFlush` enabled)](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/console.cs,372) around [a `Stream` returned by `OpenStandardOutput`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/console.cs,354)
- [`OpenStandardOutput` calls `GetStandardFile` with `stdHandleName` of `STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/console.cs,01202ef3524b1088)
- `GetStandardFile` [calls the Win32 native function `GetStdHandle`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/console.cs,483), [wraps the returned handle in `SafeFileHandle`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/console.cs,484) and then [wraps the `SafeFileHandle` in `__ConsoleStream`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/console.cs,508)
- [`TextWriter.Synchronized` returns a `SyncTextWriter`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/textwriter.cs,90877a0a3323d029)
- [`SyncTextWriter.WriteLine(string)` calls `WriteLine(string)` on the underlying `StreamWriter`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/textwriter.cs,4b5c919c3c04964c)
- [`StreamWriter` does not override `WriteLine(string)`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/streamwriter.cs), so it inherits the implementation from its base class, `TextWriter`
- [`TextWriter.WriteLine(string)` calls `Write(char[], int, int)`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/textwriter.cs,479)
- [`StreamWriter.Write(char[], int, int)` copies the characters to an internal buffer and then calls `Flush()`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/streamwriter.cs,ae2d0907887e2102)
- [`StreamWriter.Flush()` encodes characters from the internal buffer into bytes and then calls `Write(byte[], int, int)` and `Flush()` on the underlying `__ConsoleStream`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/streamwriter.cs,f11dc172664bb49c)
- [`__ConsoleStream.Write(byte[], int, int)`  calls `WriteFileNative`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/__consolestream.cs,3cff110c99e2f237)
- [`__ConsoleStream.WriteFileNative` calls the Win32 native function `WriteFile` or `WriteConsoleW`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/__consolestream.cs,15e6ee1099629f37)